# "Wear" Vs "Put on"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I was wondering which option **does not sound natural in each case and why:

**Case #1:**

> - Hey, sweet pie, you've ...... your shirt inside out. Turn it over. (Told a mother to her child.)

a. worn 
b. put on

**Case #2:**

> - Hey, sweet pie, you've ...... your shoes on the wrong feet. (Told a mother to her child.)

a. worn 
b. put on

To me, either choices work equally the same and there is not any logical reason for me to choose one between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case "put on" would be better since this is the action. And with the present perfect you are looking at the result of the action.  It makes less sense with the static "wear".

You could have said "you're wearing your shirt inside out" because "wear" already has that static sense

In the second, you've duplicated the particle "on"

> You've put <s>on</s> your shoes on the wrong feet.

Again "You're wearing" would also be possible

In casual speech, "got" is probably just as likely.

> You've got your shirt on inside-out.

And "turn it over" is non-idiomatic. (Idiomatically you'd probably say nothing, if the person doesn't know what to do to fix an inside-out shirt, then they need more help than an instruction)